# clrQuota: Cannot clear namespace quota on root

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I can set the quota for root directory in Hadoop

```
hdfs dfsadmin -setQuota 3
```

but I am unable to clear the quota for the root directory using

```
hdfs dfsadmin -clrQuota /**
```

it gives

> clrQuota: Cannot clear namespace quota on root.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution to this problem. There are multiple patches available by Apache Hadoop community but I don't know how to apply those patches.

For a temporary purpose. We can just extend the Quota limit on /.

This is the only possible solution. If you're using HDP then Hortonworks will provide you the patch with instructions to install that. But right now nothing can be done about it.

I'm facing the same issue.